# Signature uses weak digest algorithm

Tags: command-line, apt

I'm new in Ubuntu 16 and want to know, how to fix this problem.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: http://archive.canonical.com/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Comment: Lines that begin with `W:` are just warnings.  You can still run your upgrades as normal.  That warning is just that whatever site you are connecting to has a weak digest algorithm that whoever owns it needs to update it.

Comment: what Ubuntu version are you using?  are you trying to install some very old package? why are "Precise" repos being looked up?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) went end of life and that will be the reason for this problem. Are you sure you use Ubuntu 16?  You fix this by removing 12.04 related data from your system. "archive.canonical.com/dists/precise" = 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste `sudo dpkg --configure -a` into the Terminal.

Then paste `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

You can also try: `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix broken dependencies.

These commands should help you to upgrade the packages in question.

Comment: I doubt this will solve a _weak digest algorithm_.

Comment: Wont work for end of life releases. He is using something from 12.04.